# Fix broken Cockpit installation

Tags: 16.04, apt

I am trying to install Cockpit http://cockpit-project.org on my Ubuntu server 16.04

Unfortunately, I installed it a long time ago, and now that i've come back to it it won't launch and I didn't know why or where to start. So I tried to remove it and re-install to start from scratch...

So I did `sudo apt purge --auto-remove cockpit`

It processed it for a few seconds but didn't delete any of the directories, when I reinstalled it didn't overwrite any of them either :(

So I tried again, but this time deleted /etc/cockpit myself afterwards, but when I reinstall it doesn't re-create the directory either D:

What should I do next?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh... nevermind...
Turns out there was a cockpit-bridge package that was seperate, and I think cockpit-ws too.

In the end I ran `sudo apt purge --auto-remove cockpit*`

Which is... perhaps not the most elegant solution and it might have removed some important stuff, but I'm fairly certain they have all been reinstalled as I reinstalled Cockpit this time...

Anyway, it's working now, although I'm scared to restart this server at the moment...

Comment: In the end, everything was fine by the way.